# How to Resolve HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request

Tags: https, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I am trying to access an URL to an application provided by my organisation (will not be able to disclose URL). Majority of my colleagues are able to access it fine. However, I keep encountering the "HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request" error.

I have tried the fixes from https://www.itpro.com/infrastructure/network-internet/359323/what-is-http-error-400-and-how-do-you-fix-it but this issue still persists. I have tried accessing it when connected to external and corporate network and using different types of browsers.

Any idea how can I resolve it?

Comment: 1. Is the URL behind any authorization mechanism? 2 - When you say "majority" you mean all except of you or there are other people who experience the same issue? 3 - Did you try to contact your organization support? If they provided that URL to you and that URL is private (you cannot share it) they have to provide support to you as well.

Comment: Hi Alexey:
1. URL can be accessible via any network, does not have to be strictly connected to any network. However, it does require users to login. So i am not sure if there are any issues with the login mechanism (what i think you might be referring to as authorization mechanism) used for this application. 2. There are others who experiences this as well. Just that i.e. users from Country A experiences this problem but not users from other countries. 3. I am currently working with them to troubleshoot it. Just wondering if it is a browser/user issue. Appreciate your reply 